# Unexpected Error when trying to debug/release app into SharePoint 20013 from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I just create a VM to be my development environment, with a WS2008 R2 with latest service pack, has VS2013 also has a SharePoint farm. All working well.

I'm trying to create a simple app and launching it into a Development Site in this SharePoint 2013 instance. But I'm getting unexpected error after click in "trust in this app". (sometimes this trust message is even not been shown).

Full Error

An unexpected error has occurred.

Please try again by launching the app installed on your site.

Comment: did you configured your farm for app deployment ? For example `App Management Service` Service is running DNS records are configured ?

Comment: the "App Management Service " is started  ( just checked following this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179923.aspx)>


Do I have to create an isolated app domain? (at this stage) I just want to develop apps on-premises.

Comment: Have a look at [Prepare your SharePoint 2013 farm for App development and debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/how24/archive/2013/06/14/prepare-your-sharepoint-2013-farm-for-app-development-and-debugging.aspx). It is a more complete articel about how to set up the development environment. I think your missing several thinks when you have only did the steps from your article

Comment: I followed this and works : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901(v=office.15).aspx